# How to plot a heat map on 3 unordered arrays in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a set of arrays that looks like the following:

```
x=[-200,-200,-200,-200,-200, -150, -150, -150,-150, -150, -100, ...]

y=[-60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, ...] 

z=[0.2, 0.1, 0, -0.32, ...]
```

where `x`, `y` are points on a grid and `z` is a force at the corresponding `x`, `y` values. (In other words `0.2` is the value of force at the `x` coordinate `-200` and the `y` coordinate `-60`.) I would like to plot a heat map of the `z` values at each `x`, `y` point in `python`. Notice that one of the issues is that the `y` values are not in order from least to greatest. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal working answer (except import commands) for you. Replace the `x`, `y` and `z` with your actual data. I just took some random values for `z`. `return_index=True` returns the order of original unsorted unique elements.

```
x=[-200,-200,-200,-200,-200, -150, -150, -150,-150, -150, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100]
y=[-60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, -120, 0, 30, -30]
z=np.array([0.2, 0.1, 0, -0.32, 0.4, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1, 0.3, 0.4, -0.7, 0.7, 0.6, -0.3, 0.9])

x=np.unique(x)
x = np.unique(x)
y1, yind = np.unique(y, return_index=True)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y[sorted(yind)])
Z=z.reshape(len(y1),len(x), order='F')
plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X-values")
plt.ylabel("Y-values")
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bazinga. This is close to what I have attempted. However, whenever you apply `y=np.unique(y)` it reorders the array so that it is in ascending order. To see the issue, if you look in your array, at the `x` array coordinate `-100` and the `y` coordinate `30`, the value of `z` should be `-0.3` (next to last value in all three vectors), but it looks to be around `-0.7` (top right corner of graph). Please correct me if I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks for the update. This keeps the `y` index correct, but the `z` values still seem to be getting scrambled. Again, if you look at `x = -200, y = 30` the value should be `z = -0.32` (4th value in on all vectors), however the actual value looks to be `z = 0.5`. I've tried playing around with the code, but I can't figure out exactly where it is going wrong. I assume it is something in the `X`, `Y` ordering, but I can't quite determine the issue.

Comment: @KurtA Ok, I figured out the issue. The issue was in Z ordering after `reshape`. When you reshape, by default the order is row-wise. When I looked at the X, Y, Z values, I found that we needed column wise reshaping of Z. For that, you need to provide the following command `Z=z.reshape(len(y),len(x), order='F')` where `F` is for Fortran type ordering. Use this and the problem is solved. Let me know.

Comment: Something still isn't right. Again, the value for `x = -100, y = 30` should be `z=-0.3`, but it actually reads as `z = -0.1`. As another point `x = -100, y = 0' should be `z = 0.6` but looks to be `0.3` or so. Thanks for continuing to look at this. This is what I've felt like for the past week.

Comment: Uff, I managed to get the correct order of X, Y and Z. Print them and match them point by point and make sure it's printing correct values. I edited my answer above. You need more mesh points to check for the values. Currently the filled regions in the plot are kind of misleading at discrete points.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the all of the help @Bazingaa. I eventually went with the dumbest possible solution I could think of. I wrote a quick function that finds the array index I need and returns it. It isn't elegant, but it has the advantage that I can always extend it to extra dimensions if needed.

```
import numpy as np

def findxyind(xval, yval, xarray, yarray):    
    while True:
        for index in range(xarray.shape[0]):
            if xarray[index]==xval and yarray[index]==yval:
                return index

x=[-200,-200,-200,-200,-200, -150, -150, -150,-150, -150, -100, -100, -100, -100, -100]
y=[-60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, -120, 0, 30, -30, -60, -120, 0, 30, -30]
z=np.array([0.2, 0.1, 0, -0.32, 0.4, -0.2, 0.5, -0.1, 0.3, 0.4, -0.7, 0.7, 0.6, -0.3, 0.9])

x=np.asarray(x)
y=np.asarray(y)
xunique=np.unique(x)
yunique=np.unique(y)

zarray=np.empty([xunique.shape[0], yunique.shape[0]])

for i in range(xunique.shape[0]):
    for j in range(yunique.shape[0]):
        xval=xunique[i]
        yval=yunique[j]
        index=findxyind(xval, yval, x, y)
        zarray[i,j]=z[index]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xunique, yunique, indexing='ij')
plt.pcolormesh(X, Y, zarray)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("X-values")
plt.ylabel("Y-values")
```